# Yii2 - Restrict access for unconfirmed accounts

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to implement email account verification.

If a user has not confirmed their email, they can still log in, but they should not be able to access any actions in the `account` module. So for example, if they try to access:

- `/account/profile/edit`
- `/account/listing/add`

it should redirect the user to `/account/default/confirm`, which displays a message saying:

> "You have not yet confirmed your account, please click the link in the confirmation email, or click here to resend the confirmation email".

I have tried the following:

`BaseController:`

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected function findUser($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne(['id' => $id, 'deleted_at' => null])) !== null) {
            if ($model->confirmed_at == null) {
                return $this->redirect(['/account/default/confirm']);
            }

            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

`ProfileController:`

```
class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionEdit()
    {
        $user = $this->findUser(Yii::$app->user->id);
        $profile = $user->profile; // getProfile() relation in User model

        return $this->render('index', [
            'profile' => $profile,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that it gives me an error:

> "Trying to get property 'profile' of non-object".

I think the reason for the error is because it seems to be assigning the redirect to `$user`, instead of actually terminating the request at the redirect.

I know instead of doing `return $this->redirect()` in `findUser()` I can do it in the controller action, but then I would have to do this for every action. Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe some kind of access rules or behaviour?

Comment: You should try changing ´if ($model->confirmed_at == null)´ to ´if (!isset($model->profile))´ to verify that it does have a profile

Answer (score 0):

Here try to check `!empty()` before `$model` access like

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected function findUser($id)
    {
        if (($model = User::findOne(['id' => $id, 'deleted_at' => null])) !== null) {
            if (!empty($model->confirmed_at)) {
                return $model; 
            } 
            return $this->redirect(['/account/default/confirm']);                
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->redirect()` will return response object - it looks like really bad design if such method may return completely unrelated object (`Response` or `User`). You probably should call [`Application::end()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#end()-detail) to terminate application, so redirection will take effect without continuing execution of controller action.

```
protected function findUser($id) {
    if (($model = User::findOne(['id' => $id, 'deleted_at' => null])) !== null) {
        if ($model->confirmed_at == null) {
            $this->redirect(['/account/default/confirm']);
            Yii::$app->end();
        }

        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```